# Laravel 5 how to get controller display simple message box or alert?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, alert

Cannot find solution to this simple problem, i just do some voting app, and if users votes I would like to show simple alert like "Thanks" , but I cannot find the way to do it from the controller? I have tried the simple jQuery code like this but it's not working.

```
echo "<script>alert('You have already voted');</script>";
```

Any simple solutions?

```
public function voting()
{
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $id = Input::get('msg_id');
    $vote = Input::get('vote');
    $count = Voting::wheremes_id_fk($id)->whereip_add($ip)->count();

    if($count==0)
    {
        if($vote == "up")
        {
            Project::whereid($id)->increment('up');

            Voting::insert(
                array('mes_id_fk' => $id, 'ip_add' => $ip )
            );
        }
        else if ($vote=="down") {

            Project::whereid($id)->decrement('down');

            Voting::insert(
                array('mes_id_fk' => $id, 'ip_add' => $ip )
            );
        }
    } 
    else {
        // How to popup "thanks" alert??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ajax to do the vote, return a `json` response and use `JavaScript` to respond to the `json` response.

example:

```
public function vote()
{
  //your voting code
  return Response::json(['success'=>true]);
}
```

and in your `JavaScript`, check the json

```
$.post('/vote/', { id: 123   }, function(data){
    if(data.success== true)
    {
      alert('Thanks for voting);
    }
}
```

If you are not using ajax, simply use the Session flash.

i.e.,  from your controller,

```
public function vote()
{
  //your voting code
  Session::flash('msg', 'Thanks for voting');
 return Redirect::back();
}
```

and from View,

```
@if(Session::has('msg'))
  {{Session::get('msg')}}
@endif
```

Comment: i am trying to setup Session::flash message from controller but it does not firing. I am not using any redirection, i don't want to reload page , just want to make popup message with ok button

Comment: posted.. can you check